# breeze.js and independent transactions

Tags: transactions, entity, breeze

I have a need to do smaller SaveChanges outside of a larger scope SaveChanges, and I want to be able to save the smaller transactions independent of the larger one.  An example:  User is creating an order with line items.  Typical parent/child shopping cart.  All the "order" entities are being created/saved as 1 SaveChange transaction.  While the user is on the site, he may pick a product and flag it as a "favorite".  At that time I would like to save that transaction to the DB totally independent of the order (which may or may not be saved).  Would this be a case for a mutli-manager architecture?  Or multi-datacontexts?  I'm not quite sure what the differences are between the two.  Is there a best practice for this type of work flow?  If it matters, I'm using Durandal 2.0 and I'm following the singleton design pattern for my datacontext object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The argument could be made** ... perhaps *should be made* ... that your workflow shouldn't allow the user to simultaneously favorite a `Product` and build a new `Order` and have both changes be unsaved and sharing the same `EntityManager`. That seems unwise to me.

But Breeze does support partial saves ("cherry pick saves") and you can take advantage of that feature if/when you have a good reason to do so.

The first parameter of the `EntityManager.saveChanges` method is an optional array of entities to save so you can cherry pick which entities to save in a transaction.

Lots of ways to build that set. Something like this for a KO app might work (caution: untested)

```
function saveOrderById(order){
    // get the order's items with pending changes
    var itemsWithChanges = order.orderItems().filter(
        function(item) { return item.entityAspect.isAddedModifiedOrDeleted()});
    // concatenate with the order itself (you may have a concurrency property to set, btw)
    var savables = itemsWithChanges.concat(order)
    return order.entityAspect.entityManager.saveChanges(savables); // returns the promise
}
```

The favoriting of the `Product` would not be part of this transaction and would remain a pending change in cache.

**BE CAREFUL**

When cherry picking, you are at risk of omitting an entity-with-change that should be part of the transaction.

For example (a bad example perhaps), one of the new order items could reference a new `Product` that you haven't yet saved.

This is a bad example because your UI probably shouldn't work that way. I'm not a fan of adding a `Product` and using it in an `Order` at the same time or even in the same workflow.  If you tried such a thing, I'd like to think that the server would throw a referential integrity exception.

But you see my point, right? You have to be certain that your save selection has all the right stuff in it.

Comment: I really don't like the idea of cherry picking. I would like it to be isolated.  I can see this being used in a number of places. Let's say the user has an unsaved shopping cart, but before checkout they need to go into their Customer Profile and update their email address, CC info, etc. They should be able to update their Profile data while leaving the shopping cart untouched, and after updating the Profile they can continue to shop. (Profile data gets committed). User may never complete the order. I read about multiple managers.  Would that work, or is cherry picking the only option?  thanks

Comment: **Multiple managers definitely works** and, in fact, **is preferred**. I'm just saying that partial saves are available if you need them. Side note: make sure your managers share the same `metadataStore` so you don't make redundant server trips for metadata. See [`EntityManager.createEmptyCopy`](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_createEmptyCopy)